# I'm trying to append the repeated column in a dafaframe to new dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

Inuput

```
a   b   c   a   b   c   a   b   c
1   12  123 4   23  567 7   12  456
2   23  456 45  56  876 4   34  234
3   34  789 47  67  345 6   76  769
```

output

```
a   b   c
1   12  123
2   23  456
3   34  789
4   4   567
45  45  876
47  47  345
7   12  456
4   34  234
6   76  769
```

I'm trying to solve this in python

```py
for i in range(0,len(supplier.columns),len(col_list)):
    dfnew = supplier.iloc[i : i + len(col_list)]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can de-duplicate the columns with [`groupby.cumcount`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/1.3/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.cumcount.html) and compute a MultiIndex, then [`stack`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html):

```
out = (df.set_axis(pd.MultiIndex
                     .from_arrays([df.columns,
                                   df.columns.to_series()
                                     .groupby(level=0).cumcount()]),
                   axis=1)
         .stack().sort_index(level=1)
      )
```

Output:

```
      a   b    c
0 0   1  12  123
1 0   2  23  456
2 0   3  34  789
0 1   4  23  567
1 1  45  56  876
2 1  47  67  345
0 2   7  12  456
1 2   4  34  234
2 2   6  76  769
```

Or using [`groupby`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) and [`concat`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.concat.html):

```
group = df.columns.to_series().groupby(level=0).cumcount()
out = pd.concat([g for k,g in df.groupby(group, axis=1)], axis=0)
```

Output:

```
    a   b    c
0   1  12  123
1   2  23  456
2   3  34  789
0   4  23  567
1  45  56  876
2  47  67  345
0   7  12  456
1   4  34  234
2   6  76  769
```